# After updating object (_User) and later retrieving it, field is not updated (Parse)

Tags: javascript, object, parse-platform, updates

#### ISSUE

I have been trying to update a field (`gamesArray`) from the current User (`Parse.User.current()`), so later in another view I can see it. The problem is that when I do it, the field gets updated (I `console.log()` it right after the object is saved and check it on the Database UI from Parse) but when I go to the other view, in which the User is retrieved and I show the field on screen, it is not updated.

#### CONTEXT

My `_User` has an array of `Games` called `gamesArray` so I update that array just like this:

```
addGameToUser = function(game, userId) {
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userQuery.equalTo("objectId", userId);
    userQuery.first({
        success: function(user) {
            // User found
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }).then(function(user) {
        // If user is current user update it
        if(user.id == Parse.User.current().id) {
            var games = user.get('gamesArray');
            games.push(game);
            user.set('gamesArray', games);
            user.save(null, {
                success: function(user) {
                    console.log(user.get('gamesArray'));
                },
                error: function(user, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            // Call cloud function...
        }
    });
}
```

In this case, `console.log(user.get('gamesArray'))` returns the updated field. I use this function when the user creates a new game.

The problem is that in a different view, when I retrieve the user and get that field, it is not updated:

```
getUserGames: function() {
    var games = Parse.User.current().get('gamesArray');
    console.log(games);
}
```

Here, `console.log(games)` is printing the old field value. So if I had 4 games in the array, the previous function printed 5 (4 plus the created one) and this still prints 4.

I thought that maybe I was not saving the `Game` properly, but this is the output of the Parse's Database UI `gamesArray` column of the current User:

```
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Game","objectId":"..."}]
```

The only way that I can get the updated field is **logging out and logging in with the same user**.

#### QUESTIONS

Why is that? What am I doing wrong? How could I "*update*" the user so I don't have to log out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your user object that you are reading from is not the same specific object that you are updating. So you are updating the object in your database, but the user object you're reading from doesn't know that the object in the database has been updated.  You should try fetching the user first. iOS has a fetchIfNeeded method.

Comment: That's it :) I was using `Parse.User.current()` and as it states in the docs: `Retrieves the currently logged in ParseUser with a valid session, either from memory or localStorage, if necessary.`. So I understand that it was getting the user from localStorage, not from the DB. Thanks ;)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  It would suck to have to fetch before doing anything with your user, so maybe put a fetchIfNeeded call in the callback of any cloud function call that you know will update your user, if you are using server side code.  That will ensure that you have the most up to date values without having to wait to check before doing anything, which is annoying from a user standpoint.